# How to Dynamically increase height of Two Tableview in a Scrollview

Tags: ios, swift

I have an issue at the moment I am trying to put two table views inside a scrollview in one controller and these tableview are placed one below another. these two tableview uses scrollview for scrolling.
so I used vertical stackview inside scrollview. but when I create cell, both tableview height is not increases as well as scrollview is not able to scroll.
How should i use scrollview scroll for scrolling tableview?

-- scrollview
-----VerticalStackView
--------Tableview 1
--------Tableview 2

I'm really lost with this.Any help will be greatly appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

I have came up with the solution. well, its not the perfect solution but its what we Indian call "Jugaad". first I have created a variable of array of IndexPaths.

```
var commentLoadedIndex: [IndexPath] = []
```

after that I added code shown below in cellforRowat function of tableView:

```
cell.layoutIfNeeded()
if commentLoadedIndex.contains(where: { ind in
            ind.row == indexPath.row && ind.section == indexPath.section
        }) {
            
        } else {
            commentLoadedIndex.append(indexPath)
            commentsTableHeight.constant += cell.contentView.frame.height
        }
```

so now with every cell load height will automatically increases.
Now if you are calling API & Reloading table,
Then every time you reload table you have to set table height to maybe 1 because if height is zero functions won't be called & set created index path array to blank array.

you can take multiple arrays for multiple table & you are good to go.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make each `UITableView` define it's own size based on their content. To do that subclass both of them using the class below.

```swift
final class ContentSizedTableView: UITableView {
    
    override var contentSize:CGSize {
        didSet {
            invalidateIntrinsicContentSize()
        }
    }

    override var intrinsicContentSize: CGSize {
        layoutIfNeeded()
        return CGSize(width: UIView.noIntrinsicMetric, height: contentSize.height)
    }
}
```

Then, for each `UITableView` you need to set `isScrollEnabled = false`. Otherwise their defined size will be 0.

Then just add each table view to the stack view you're using inside the scrollview. If their combined height is larger than the screen height, it'll scroll.